# Array Filter to fitler arrays in php

Tags: php

How can I remove an item based on key for example, `$array[testing3]` or based on value, for example, `Template3` from the below array in php.

```
$array = array(
    'mentor' => 'Template',
    'mentor1' => 'Template1',
    'testing' => 'Template2',
    'testing3' => 'Template3',
    'testing4' => 'Template4',
    'testing5' => 'Template5',
    'testing6' => 'Template6'
);
```

Comment: I'm amazed that none of the answers has mentioned or corrected the duplicate key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use `array_filter()` to achieve the goal.

```
$array = array(
    'mentor' => 'Template',
    'mentor1' => 'Template1',
    'testing' => 'Template2',
    'testing3' => 'Template3',
    'testing4' => 'Template4',
    'testing5' => 'Template5',
    'testing6' => 'Template6'
);
```

Remove an item in an array, for example, `Template3`

```
$filtered_array1 = array_filter($array, function($val) {
    return 'Template3' != $val;
});

print_r($filtered_array1);
```

Remove all elements in an array except `Template3` from the array

```
$filtered_array2 = array_filter($array, function($val) {
    return 'Template3' == $val;
});

print_r($filtered_array2);
```

So far, we used value to filter an array. You can filter an array based on `key` too. You need to use 3rd argument to the function. There two options for the 3rd argument - `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` and `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH`. You may use one of them. Let's use `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` flag to remove an item based on `key`, for example, `testing3`:

```
$filtered_array3 = array_filter($array, function($key) {
    return 'testing3' != $key;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

print_r($filtered_array3);
```

To know more about `array_filter()` function please refer to this [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter)

Answer (score 3):

You can use **unset()** to achieve this:

```
unset(myArray['testing3']);
```

Comment: Use the other answer by Jeff if you are not aware of the key name and wish to remove by value

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unset` (https://www.php.net/unset)

```
$array = array(
  'mentor' => 'Template',
  'mentor1' => 'Template1',
  'testing' => 'Template2',
  'testing3' => 'Template3',
  'testing4' => 'Template4',
  'testing5' => 'Template5',
  'testing6' => 'Template6');

  unset($array['testing3']);
```

or if you need to find it by the value you can use the `array_search` (https://www.php.net/array-search)

```
// Remove the element if it exists
if($element = array_search("Template3",$array)){
  unset($array[$element]);
}
```

To answer the question brought up in the comments about keeping only the array element you're looking for: 
use `array_search` and overwrite your array (or create a new array from it).

```
$array = array_search('Template3', $array);
```

Comment: If "Template3" is not found in the array this will unset `$array[0]` (if it exists). You should check the result of `array_search` is not false.

Comment: How can I remove all elements in an array except Template3 from the array?

Comment: @James using `array_filter()` you can do that.

Comment: @unclexo why not just reset the array as testing3? e.g. `$array = array('testing3' => 'Template3');` or array_search (e.g. `$array = array_search('Template3', $array);`

Comment: Well, you can do that when you know both key and value. But there are situations when you don't know one of them. Therefore, key or value can be dynamic. Otherwise, you can manipulate array items better using `array_filter()`.